# MySQL One to many in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables, One is **companyDetails** the other is **classDetails**.

Each company can have taken multiple classes. I need to set this up in phpMyAdmin using Foreign Keys.

What field type should I use to store multiple class id's in the company?

I'm confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I would go with 3 tables:
companydetails, classdetail, and companyclass.
I would connect  companydetails.id with companyclass.company_id and classdetail.id with companyclass.class_id
Assuming that different firms can go to the same class, that is why I would rather go with new table. 
You could go with only companydetails and classdetail and make relation between companydetails.id(pk) with clasdetail.company_id(fk), but first solution is better so you don't have to repeat names of classes multiple times 
Hope this helps

Comment: I am glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better if you create another table that lists classes in a single company

Comment: Okay, even then the new table contains 2 cols.

company id INT(12)
multiple Class ID's ???

And how do i setup a foreign key constraint?

Comment: You can set it in structure -> relations and set it up there or u can use this statement                              ALTER TABLE tablename
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_con_name
FOREIGN KEY (id)
REFERENCES othertable(id)